# AWS Release Pipeline CodeCommit(repo A) -> CodeBuild -> CodeCommit(repo B) -> Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-codecommit

I am trying to create a release pipeline, where my source code is in CodeCommit(repo A) and I use Codebuild for build once code build for repo A is completed in the pipeline I want the artifact to be committed to repo B aa a part of release pipeline and then finally I want to take the source from repo B and deploy it to Beanstalk. I am trying to create this as a part of the release pipeline using the code pipeline.

But I am not able to figure out how to commit the artifact(built using code build) to repo B in the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

You can 'git push' the artifact to the other repo using regular git commands in buildspec. A better approach would be to copy the artifact to S3 using aws cli command (e.g. aws s3 cp) and create the second pipeline with the source as this s3 bucket/object. This way you can kick start the second pipeline by just copying the artifact to the S3 bucket.

Comment: No, I don't want to push it to S3 because I want to push artifact to repo A and deploy to EB from B repo(along with artifact and other code parts of repo B)